# django custom modal error messages doesn' work

Tags: django

I'm using django to write a web application and I come across some problems when I write custome error messages.

First is EmailField.I want it show " instead of "Enter a valid email address"

Here is my code. It fails, and I wonder why?

```
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name="邮件",
    max_length=100,
    unique=True,
    blank=True,
    error_messages={
        'unique': '邮箱已被注册'
    },
    validators=[EmailValidator(message="邮箱不合法")]
)
```

Second is about the username. I want it show "用户名未填" when user submit a blank value, But I always get "这个字段是必填项", which maybe the default message.

I tried blank, null, required, but none of then works.

Here is my code

```
username = models.CharField(
    verbose_name="用户名",
    max_length=14,
    unique=True,
    error_messages={
        'null': '用户名未填null',
        'blank': '用户名未填blank',
        'required': '用户名未填',
        'unique': '用户名已被注册'
    }
)
```

Here is part of my template code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="registerUsername" class="col-sm-4 control-label">用户名</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerUsername" placeholder="请输入用户名">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="registerEMail" class="col-sm-4 control-label">E-mail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerEMail" placeholder="请输入email">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is part of my form

```
class BlogUserCreationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = BlogUser
```

I'm confused. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Please update your question and paste the relevant part of your template code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have pasted my template code. @Selcuk

Comment: The `input` fields in your template do not have a `name` attribute, how will it even work? Can you show us your form/s ?

Comment: OK. I use ajax to submit my form